# Was Castro City ever a city?

Tags: 20th-century, california, toponymy

I obtained a map of a South-East SF Bay.

Officially it is *Page 8* of *San Francisco, Oakland, Fremont, Berkeley* set, compiled by the Soviet Main Intelligence Department of General Staff (ГРУ ГШ) in 1976.

It has a few funny mistakes (e.g. SLAC is marked as an *Industrial Enterprise*). One thing baffled me seriously. An area enclosed between San Antonio Road and Castro Street, and El Camino Real and Alma Street, is marked as **Castro City**. The city of Mountain View, according to the map, is East of Castro Street.

Here is a relevant part:

[image]

The boldface at the top left says **Кастро Сити** (Castro City). The boldface at the bottom right says **Маунтин Вью** (Mountain View).

I know very well of a California Castro family. However I have never heard of a Castro City before. Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: Does this help? [Castro Family History | Castro & Rengstorff Park](https://mountainviewhistorical.org/castro-city-rengstorff-park/) and [CASTRO CITY](https://deleonrealty.com/neighborhoods/mountain-view/castro-city/)

Comment: How is this about history? The single link to show this on openstreetmap: https://www.openstreetbrowser.org/#map=15/37.4025/-122.1036

Comment: @LаngLаngС - How this neighbourhood ended with that name is an historical question. The question title, however, is a bit misleading because it can be understood as a different question that, in this case, has a non historical answer.

Comment: @user58697 Could you clarify the title? If you feel it could be misleading or could be understood as a different question, could you revise the title to clearly ask what you want to know, and attract the right sort of researchers to your question?

Comment: @MCW - It's not my question. It's somebody else's interesting historical question.

Comment: @Pere As is, it is not a historical Q. _You_ seem to be able to transform this question in your mind, as in your reading it would be a historical one. So why not apply this transformation as a suggestion/[edit] to make that clearer for all readers? (I'd tend to agree to what you offer in comments, albeit that would be deviating from all the intent I could extract from the current version. That may be worth a try, if QP agrees to it.)

Comment: @LarsBosteen Thanks for the links. As I said, I am well aware of Castro family, and a Rengdorff family as well. The question is, did Castro City ever exist as a city, and if it was when it ceased to exist. If not, why the map shows it as a city?

Comment: Then the whole 'soviet' angle seems _utterly_ redundant & a veritable distraction.. Maps, including the one I gave, also show this location named the same way. Please remove it & update the Q according to the new title. Please lift the info in comments into Q & include your own prior research. (Personally, I'd like to see _some_ rationale for dispelling this notion: that this looks as if one would assume any Chinatown or similar agglomeration/naming similar to that would be treated with the same thinking?)

Comment: @LаngLаngС A pap is not redundant. The whole point of the question is that the map spells Castro City and Mountain View in the same font size, as if Castro City was a municipality of the same status. And I normally trust ГРУ ГШ.

Comment: Well, that line of reasoning should be _in_ the question (and isn't clear to me even now, since the pic lacks sharpness). And still I miss prior research: whether you compared that one old map with other maps, either older, as old or newer than the one above, to answer this. Don't trust _any one piece of info,_ compare, always.

Comment: @LаngLаngС: So your piece of advice would be to never automatically trust any piece of advice ?

Comment: @Lucian Indeed, my Cretan heritage shines today?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be 1:50000 (or maybe even 1:25000?) map. That would likely mean that top-level labels will be district subdivisions, and both Castro-City and Mountain View were seen as districts within larger San Francisco area. District divisions on these soviet maps sometimes do not fit with actual administrative divisions on locations; for example, I've seen a similar map of Paris with districts named "Boulogne" and "Billancourt" - whereas actually it would be one commune named "Boulogne-Billancourt". Why map-makers decided to elevate a small neighborhood to the same level as Mountain View - might be a mistake in information-gathering, might be an attempt to put more toponyms on the map for ease of navigation? Anyway, it is not indicative of marked area being an actual city/town/whatever at any point in its history.

Comment: It is 1:25000 indeed